# What is the best way to implement the timer?

Tags: java, android, android-progressbar

I'm writing an Android quiz app that needs to show a timer. What is the best way to implement the timer?
I'm new to android and this is my first app. I tried using Handlers. This works but doesn't seem to be efficient.

```
public class PertanyaanActivity extends Activity
{

    private Handler progressBarHandler = new Handler();
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    TextView progressText;
    PertanyaanData mQuestionData;
    JawabanData mAnswerData;

    private int mCategoryId;
    private Map<Integer, Pertanyaan> mQuestions;
    private Map<Integer, Jawaban> mAnswers;

    private List<Integer> mQuestionIndexList;
    private int mNextQuestionIndex = 0;

    private int mTotalQuestions = 0;
    private int mQuestionsAnswered = 0;
    private int mCorrectAnswers = 0;

    private Pertanyaan mCurrentQuestion;

    private List<Button> answerButtons;

    private LinearLayout.LayoutParams mAnswerButtonLayout;

  //  private TextView mViewHeader;
    private ScrollView mQuestionScrollView;
    private TextView mQuestionText;
    private LinearLayout mAnswersFrame;
    private TextView mQuestionDescriptionText;
   // private Button mNextQuestionButton;
  //  private Button mCompleteButton;
    private int max_salah = 0;
    private  int progressBarStatus = 0;
    private long fileSize = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.question);
        mCategoryId = getIntent().getIntExtra("categoryId", 0);

        Log.i(Constants.APP_LOG_NAME, "Getting question for category ID " + mCategoryId);

        mAnswerButtonLayout = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        mAnswerButtonLayout.setMargins(30, 20, 30, 0);

       // mViewHeader = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.viewHeader);
        mQuestionScrollView = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.questionScrollView);
        mQuestionText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.questionText);
        mAnswersFrame = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.answersFrame);

        progressText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.progressText);
        progressBar= (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.ProgressBar01);
      //  progressBar.setProgress(0);
        //progressBar.setMax(100);
        waktu();
        //mQuestionDescriptionText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.questionDescriptionText);
     //   mNextQuestionButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.nextQuestionButton);
        //mCompleteButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.completeButton);

        mQuestionData = new PertanyaanData(this);
        mAnswerData = new JawabanData(this);

        mQuestions = mQuestionData.getQuestionsByCategoryId(mCategoryId);

        mQuestionIndexList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int questionId : mQuestions.keySet())
        {
            mQuestionIndexList.add(questionId);
        }

        Collections.shuffle(mQuestionIndexList);

        if (mQuestionIndexList.size() > (Constants.MAX_QUESTIONS_PER_ROUND))
        {
            mQuestionIndexList = mQuestionIndexList.subList(0, Constants.MAX_QUESTIONS_PER_ROUND);
        }

        mTotalQuestions = mQuestionIndexList.size();

        Log.i(Constants.APP_LOG_NAME, "Total questions: " + mTotalQuestions);

        if (mTotalQuestions > 0)
        {
            displayNextQuestion();
        }
        else
        {
            Log.e(Constants.APP_LOG_NAME, "No questions found for category ID " + mCategoryId);
        }

        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();

        if (mQuestionData != null)
        {
            mQuestionData.close();
        }

        if (mAnswerData != null)
        {
            mAnswerData.close();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Displays the next available question in the current trivia round.
     */
    public void displayNextQuestion()
    {
        // Reset ScrollView position.
        mQuestionScrollView.scrollTo(0, 0);

        waktu();
        mCurrentQuestion = getNextQuestion();

        String headerText = getString(R.string.question)
                + " " + mNextQuestionIndex
                + " " + getString(R.string.of)
                + " " + mTotalQuestions;

        //mViewHeader.setText(headerText);

        //nyalakanWaktu();
        //waktu();
        displayQuestion(mCurrentQuestion);

       // mQuestionDescriptionText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       // mNextQuestionButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    /**
     * Gets the next available question in the current trivia round.
     *
     * @return Question - The instance of the next available question.
     */
    private Pertanyaan getNextQuestion()
    {
        int nextQuestionId = mQuestionIndexList.get(mNextQuestionIndex);

        Log.i(Constants.APP_LOG_NAME, "Got next question ID " + nextQuestionId);

        Pertanyaan question = mQuestions.get(nextQuestionId);

        if (question == null)
        {
            Log.w(Constants.APP_LOG_NAME, "Next question is null.");
        }

        mNextQuestionIndex++;

        return question;
    }

    /**
     * Displays a question on the screen.
     *
     * @param Question question - The question instance to display.
     */
    private void displayQuestion(Pertanyaan question)
    {
        if (question != null)
        {
            mAnswers = mAnswerData.getAnswersByQuestionId(question.getPertanyaanId());

            List<Integer> answerIndexList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            for (int answerId : mAnswers.keySet())
            {
                answerIndexList.add(answerId);
            }

            Collections.shuffle(answerIndexList);

            mAnswersFrame.removeAllViews();

            mQuestionText.setText(question.getText());

            if (mAnswers != null)
            {
                answerButtons = new ArrayList<Button>();

                Jawaban answer = null;

                for (int answerId : answerIndexList)
                {
                    Log.i(Constants.APP_LOG_NAME, "Adding answer ID " + answerId);

                    answer = mAnswers.get(answerId);

                    Button answerButton = new Button(this);
                    answerButton.setId(answer.getJawabanId());
                    answerButton.setText(answer.getText());
                    answerButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_normal);

                    answerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        public void onClick(View v)
                        {
                            disableAnswerButtons();

                            answerButtonClickHandler(v);
                        }
                    });

                    answerButtons.add(answerButton);

                    mAnswersFrame.addView(answerButton, mAnswerButtonLayout);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // TODO: Need to handle this in a more user-friendly way.
            mQuestionText.setText("Null question.");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Click handler for answer option buttons.
     * Determines the result of the user selecting an answer.
     *
     * @param View v - The current view.
     */
    public void answerButtonClickHandler(View v)
    {
        Jawaban answer = mAnswers.get(v.getId());

        if (answer != null)
        {
            mQuestionsAnswered++;

            if (answer.isCorrect())
            {
                mCorrectAnswers++;

                v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.answer_button_correct);

                Suara.playButtonClickSuccess();
            }
            else
            {
                max_salah++;
                v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.answer_button_incorrect);

                Suara.playButtonClickFailure();

            }

           // mQuestionDescriptionText.setText(mCurrentQuestion.getDescription());
            //mQuestionDescriptionText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            if (mNextQuestionIndex < mQuestionIndexList.size() && max_salah < 3)
            {
                //mNextQuestionButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                //nyalakanWaktu();
                waktu();
                displayNextQuestion();
            }
            else
            {


                Intent i = new Intent(this, SummaryActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("categoryId", mCategoryId);
                i.putExtra("questionsAnswered", mQuestionsAnswered);
                i.putExtra("correctAnswers", mCorrectAnswers);
                startActivity(i);
                //mCompleteButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Click handler for the next question button.
     * Displays the next available question after current question is answered.
     *
     * @param View v - The current view.
     */
    public void nextQuestionButtonClickHandler(View v)
    {
        displayNextQuestion();

        Suara.playButtonClick();
    }

    /**
     * Click handler for the trivia round completion button.
     * Displays the round summary screen when clicked.
     *
     * @param View v - The current view.
     */
    public void completeButtonClickHandler(View v)
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, SummaryActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("categoryId", mCategoryId);
        i.putExtra("questionsAnswered", mQuestionsAnswered);
        i.putExtra("correctAnswers", mCorrectAnswers);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    /**
     * Disables all answer buttons.
     * Used after an answer is selected.
     */
    private void disableAnswerButtons()
    {
        Button answerButton = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < answerButtons.size(); i++)
        {
            answerButton = answerButtons.get(i);
            answerButton.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    public void nyalakanWaktu(){
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            progressBar.incrementProgressBy(1);
                            int stringProgress=progressBar.getProgress();
                            progressText.setText(stringProgress+"");
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

        };timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 200);
        //audioBackground.stop();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CountDownTimer`

```
     new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         mTextField.setText("done!");
     }
  }.start();
```

I think its better to use `CountDownTimer` when you have time limit. In above sample 30000 is time limit and has interval of 1000 milliseconds. After 30 minutes the `onfinish()` will get called. and you can write your logic for time spent on `onTick()`.

Better explained [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)

Comment: yes i have using it, but would you show me how to check completed progressbar, so when timer is stop will display next question ,

Comment: @FarihulRouf maybe consider asking a new question, with an example of how you are using the timer? Meenaxi did, however answer the question you asked. Good luck with the application :)